# Identifying data points amongst background noise for binned data R

Tags: r, histogram, density-plot

Not sure whether this should go on cross validated or not but we'll see. Basically I obtained data from an instrument just recently (masses of compounds from 0 to 630) which I binned into 0.025 bins before plotting a histogram as seen below:-
[image]

I want to identify the bins that are of high frequency and that stands out from against the background noise (the background noise increases as you move from right to left on the a-xis). Imagine drawing a curve line ontop of the points that have almost blurred together into a black lump and then selecting the bins that exists above that curve to further investigate, that's what I'm trying to do. I just plotted a kernel density plot to see if I could over lay that ontop of my histogram and use that to identify points that exist above the plot. However, the density plot in no way makes any headway with this as the densities are too low a value (see the second plot). Does anyone have any recommendations as to how I Can go about solving this problem? The blue line represents the density function plot overlayed and the red line represents the ideal solution (need a way of somehow automating this in R)
[image]

The data below is only part of my dataset so its not really a good representation of my plot (which contains just about 300,000 points) and as my bin sizes are quite small (0.025) there's just a huge spread of data (in total there's 25,000 or so bins).

```
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
   values
1 323.881306
2   1.003373
3  14.982121
4  27.995091
5  28.998639
6  95.983138
7  2.0117459
8  1.9095478
9  1.0072853
10  0.9038475
11  0.0055748
12  7.0964916
13  8.0725191
14  9.0765316
15  14.0102531
16  15.0137390
17  19.7887675
18  25.1072689
19  25.8338140
20  30.0151683
21  34.0635308
22  42.0393751
23  42.0504938
")
bin <- seq(0, 324, by = 0.025)
hist(df$values, breaks = bin, prob=TRUE, col = "grey")
lines(density(df$values), col = "blue")
```

Comment: Making a (perhaps simulated) random example would go a long way to having people help you--as well as sharing code, of course. Kernel density seems like a great way to go, what bandwidth did you use? I'd try some stuff out and look for a solution if you provide a starting point.

Comment: :p shall update my post in just a second. I didn't set any particular bandwithc I just used the default settings

Comment: What I've done so far is pretty basic. Tried to do it with ggplot originally but because my bin sizes are small it just wouldn't fly

Comment: Sorry the default bandwith that was used was 8.28 (it's 1am here, a bit tired and out of it)

Comment: I understand how you could have trouble deciding between the two websites: is it a signal processing/ programming issue (e.g., manipulating a bandwidth parameter), or is it a statistical problem? I think it's the later because you said that the variance (noise) is a function of the X axis, and once I read that I started thinking of a model to describe this behavior. I would begin by treating your "data" as the set of x and y values used in the histogram – bin ranges and frequencies in each bin (not the raw data). Then I would treat the data like a time series, using a spline or Kalman filter

Comment: You're right about it being a statistical problem and I'll have a look into it and report back!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're dealing with a vector `bin.densities` that has the densities for each bin, a simple way to find outliers would be:

1. look at a window around each bin, say +- 50 bins

   `current.bin <- 1`

   `window.size <- 50`

   `window <- bin.densities[current.bin-window.size : current.bin+window.size]`
2. find the 95% upper and lower quantile value (or really any value you think works)

   `lower.quant <- quantile(window, 0.05)`

   `upper.quant <- quantile(window, 0.95)`
3. then say that the current bin is an outlier if it falls outside your quantile range.

   `this.is.too.high <- (bin.densities[current.bin] > upper.quant`

   `this.is.too.low <- (bin.densities[current.bin] < lower.quant)`

   `#final result`

   `this.is.outlier <- this.is.too.high | this.is.too.low`

I haven't actually tested this code, but this is the general approach I would take. You can play around with window size and the quantile percentages until the results look reasonable. Again, not exactly super complex math but hopefully it helps.

Comment: Seems like an interesting way of doing it, I'll give it a go now

Comment: Hmm having troubles at the moment getting that vector of bin.densities. Just currently trying to find a way of calculating it

Comment: If you assign the histogram to a variable like: `bin.hist <- hist(df$values, breaks = bin, prob=TRUE, col = "grey")` then you can use `bin.hist$counts` as your `bin.densities`.